# How does std::move convert expressions to rvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, stdmove

I don't fully understand the implementation of `std::move()`.
Namely, I am confused by this implementation in the MSVC standard library:

> ```cpp
> template<class _Ty> inline
> typename tr1::_Remove_reference<_Ty>::_Type&&
> move(_Ty&& _Arg)
> { // forward _Arg as movable
>     return ((typename tr1::_Remove_reference<_Ty>::_Type&&)_Arg);
> }
> ```

When I call `std::move` like this:

```
Object obj1;
Object obj2 = std::move(obj1); // _Ty&& _Arg binds to obj1
```

... the `_Arg` reference parameter binds to the lvalue `obj1`.
You cannot directly bind an rvalue reference to an lvalue, which makes me think that a cast to an rvalue reference like `(Object&&)` is required.
However, this is absurd because `std::move()` must work for all the values.

To fully understand how this works, I've looked at the implementation of `std::remove_reference` too:

> ```cpp
> template<class _Ty>
> struct _Remove_reference
> { // remove reference
>     typedef _Ty _Type;
> };
>
> template<class _Ty>
> struct _Remove_reference<_Ty&>
> { // remove reference
>     typedef _Ty _Type;
> };
>
> template<class _Ty>
> struct _Remove_reference<_Ty&&>
> { // remove rvalue reference
>     typedef _Ty _Type;
> };
> ```

Unfortunately it's still as confusing and I don't get it.
Please help me understand the implementation of `std::move`.

Comment: @NicolBolas On the contrary, the question itself shows that OP is underselling themself in that statement. It's precisely OP's *grasp* of basic syntax skills that allows them to even pose the question.

Comment: I disagree anyway - you can learn quickly or already have a good grasp of computer science or programming as a whole, even in C++, and still struggle with the syntax. It's better to spend your time learning mechanics, algorithms, etc. but rely on references to brush up on syntax as needed, than it is to be technically articulate but to have a shallow understanding of things like copy/move/forward. How are you supposed to know "when and how to use std::move when you want to move construct something" before you know what move does?

Comment: I think I came here to understand how `move` works rather than how it's implemented.  I find this explanation really useful: https://pagefault.blog/2018/03/01/common-misconception-with-cpp-move-semantics/.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

We start with the move function (which I cleaned up a little bit):

```
template <typename T>
typename remove_reference<T>::type&& move(T&& arg)
{
  return static_cast<typename remove_reference<T>::type&&>(arg);
}
```

---

Let's start with the easier part - that is, when the function is called with rvalue:

```
Object a = std::move(Object());
// Object() is temporary, which is prvalue
```

and our `move` template gets instantiated as follows:

```
// move with [T = Object]:
remove_reference<Object>::type&& move(Object&& arg)
{
  return static_cast<remove_reference<Object>::type&&>(arg);
}
```

Since `remove_reference` converts `T&` to `T` or `T&&` to `T`, and `Object` is not reference, our final function is:

```
Object&& move(Object&& arg)
{
  return static_cast<Object&&>(arg);
}
```

Now, you might wonder: do we even need the cast? The answer is: yes, we do. The reason is simple; named rvalue reference *is* treated as lvalue (and implicit conversion from lvalue to rvalue reference is forbidden by standard).

---

Here's what happens when we call `move` with lvalue:

```
Object a; // a is lvalue
Object b = std::move(a);
```

and corresponding `move` instantiation:

```
// move with [T = Object&]
remove_reference<Object&>::type&& move(Object& && arg)
{
  return static_cast<remove_reference<Object&>::type&&>(arg);
}
```

Again, `remove_reference` converts `Object&` to `Object` and we get:

```
Object&& move(Object& && arg)
{
  return static_cast<Object&&>(arg);
}
```

Now we get to the tricky part: what does `Object& &&` even mean and how can it bind to lvalue?

To allow perfect forwarding, C++11 standard provides special rules for reference collapsing, which are as follows:

```
Object &  &  = Object &
Object &  && = Object &
Object && &  = Object &
Object && && = Object &&
```

As you can see, under these rules `Object& &&` actually means `Object&`, which is plain lvalue reference that allows binding lvalues.

Final function is thus:

```
Object&& move(Object& arg)
{
  return static_cast<Object&&>(arg);
}
```

which is not unlike the previous instantiation with rvalue - they both cast its argument to rvalue reference and then return it. The difference is that first instantiation can be used with rvalues only, while the second one works with lvalues.

---

To explain why do we need `remove_reference` a bit more, let's try this function

```
template <typename T>
T&& wanna_be_move(T&& arg)
{
  return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}
```

and instantiate it with lvalue.

```
// wanna_be_move [with T = Object&]
Object& && wanna_be_move(Object& && arg)
{
  return static_cast<Object& &&>(arg);
}
```

Applying the reference collapsing rules mentioned above, you can see we get function that is unusable as `move` (to put it simply, you call it with lvalue, you get lvalue back). If anything, this function is the identity function.

```
Object& wanna_be_move(Object& arg)
{
  return static_cast<Object&>(arg);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Although I understand that for an lvalue it is a good idea to evaluate `T` as `Object&`, I didn't know that this is really done. I would have expected `T` to also evaluate to `Object` in this case, as I thought this was the reason for introducing wrapper references and `std::ref`, or wasn't it.

Comment: Is [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Wrapper_reference) outdated/misinformed or is there a hidden difference I have not realized?

Comment: There's a difference between `template <typename T> void f(T arg)` (which is what is in the Wikipedia article) and `template <typename T> void f(T& arg)`. The first one resolves to value (and if you want to pass reference, you have to wrap it in `std::ref`), while the second one always resolves to reference. Sadly, rules for template argument deduction are rather complex, so I cannot provide precise reasoning why `T&&` resovles to `Object& &&` (but it happens indeed).

Comment: This is extremely well done explaining why you must cast. From reading some of the proposals and draft standards you would not pick that up. For example the demo implementation of move at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html#Move_Semantics lacks the cast.

Comment: @nixeagle: The reason is that the proposal for rvalue references went through quite a few changes. If I'm not mistaken, the rules allowed to omit the cast at some point.

Comment: @MarkIngram: I really meant "prvalue". :) It's a techincal term defined by the C++ standard, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602 .

Comment: But, is there any reason that this direct approach would not work? `template <typename T>
T&& also_wanna_be_move(T& arg)
{
  return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}`

Comment: That explains why remove_reference is necessary, but I still don't get why the function has to take T&& (instead of T&). If I understand this explanation correctly, it shouldn't matter whether you get a T&& or T& because either way, remove_reference will cast it to T, then you'll add back the &&. So why not say you accept a T& (which semantically is what you're accepting), instead of T&& and relying on perfect forwarding to allow the caller to pass a T&?

Comment: @mgiuca: If you want `std::move` to only cast lvalues to rvalues, then yes, `T&` would be okay. This trick is done mostly for flexibility: you can call `std::move` on everything (rvalues included) and get rvalue back.

Comment: As additional note (if T is a template parameter), T&& is called "the universal reference", since it binds everything.

Comment: The types may work out, but I was really stuck on what it means to move something in the first place. It's a misnomer, isn't it? Nothing moves when you create a reference to an existing rvalue or creating a new rvalue to refer to, etc. - the original lvalue or rvalue is still in the scope it started in, has the same address as before, etc. What would moving (the bytes of) a value mean if not copying them to their destination?

Comment: I wish I could *un-see* this. lol

Answer (score 4):

_Ty is a template parameter, and in this situation

```
Object obj1;
Object obj2 = std::move(obj1);
```

_Ty is type "Object &"

which is why the _Remove_reference is necessary.

It would be more like

```
typedef Object& ObjectRef;
Object obj1;
ObjectRef&& obj1_ref = obj1;
Object&& obj2 = (Object&&)obj1_ref;
```

If we didn't remove the reference it would be like we were doing

```
Object&& obj2 = (ObjectRef&&)obj1_ref;
```

But ObjectRef&& reduces to Object &, which we couldn't bind to obj2.

The reason it reduces this way is to support perfect forwarding.  See [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1385.htm#s7).

Comment: This doesn't explain everything about why the `_Remove_reference_` is necessary. For instance, if you have `Object&` as a typedef, and you take a reference to it, you still get `Object&`. Why doesn't that work with &&? There _is_ an answer to that, and it has to do with perfect forwarding.

Comment: True.  And the answer is very interesting.  A & && is reduced to A &, so if we tried to use (ObjectRef &&)obj1_ref, we would get Object & instead in this case.