# Calling pointer and reference method

Tags: c++, pointers

If there's one method that takes pointer as a parameter, and another overloaded method that takes a reference as a parameter, how do I call one or the other specifically?

For example.

```
int foo (int const& lippman) { \do something }
int foo (int && lippman) { \do something else }
```

--
So now when I want to call one or the other, how do I call it/how does the compiler distinguish the two(obviously by parameter, but how?)

Thanks

Comment: None of these takes a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both functions have references as parameters, the first an lvalue reference, the second an rvalue reference.

The first one overload will be called with lvalues, the second with rvalues:

```
int i = 42;
foo(i);  // first one gets called
foo(42); // second one gets called
```

This behaviour is set out in the C++ standard, and compilers need to be able to figure out what is an lvalue and what is an rvalue, to pick the correct overload.

Note that you can use `std::move` to make an lvalue look like an rvalue:

```
foo(std::move(i)); // second overload gets called
```

See a [working example](http://ideone.com/se3cWz).

Comment: So what is with the down-vote? If there is something wrong with the answer I'll be happy to fix it.

Comment: How is it that std::move(i) is taken as a rvalue??

Comment: @user3258312 It is a clever combination of casting to rvalue reference `&&` and hiding the name. See [this related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510182/how-does-stdmove-transfer-values-into-rvalues).

Answer (score 3):

```
int foo (X const&);
int foo (X&&);
```

These are not by pointer. The first is by const reference, the second is by r-value reference. To distinguish between them:

```
X x{};
foo( x ); // call the first version
foo( std::move(x) ); // call the second version (also with temporary: foo( X{} ); )
```

Note: A third overload (by pointer) would be:

```
int foo(X* x); // or "const X* x" or "const X* const x"
```

To call with the same x instance as above:

```
foo(&x); // get address of x and pass to "foo"
```