# Visual studio not following moving semantic

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2015, move-semantics

I am trying this code in Visual Studio 2015 v4.

```
using namespace std;

void * operator new(size_t size) {
    cout << "Creating new " << endl;
    void * p = malloc(size);
    return p;
}


class CTest {
private:
    string a;
    string b;
public:
    CTest( const string &&one , const string && two  ) :a(move(one)), b(move(two)) {}
};


int main() {
    CTest("one", "one" );
    return 0;   
}
```

This code outputs "Creating new" 4 times in Visual studio , which means it allocates memory 4 times. However following semantics it should only allocate twice ( creating 2 literals in data segment , creating one and two function argument = 2 allocs , and then moving their resource to a and b member variable )

Compiling this under g++ outputs "Creating new" twice, as it should.

Is there any settings i need to set in order for VS to follow moving semantics? It should be supported by default as far as i know.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1) `std::move` does not move, especially if you pass by `const &&`. See answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595117/why-can-we-use-stdmove-on-a-const-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497830/move-constructor-and-stdmove-confusion).

2) Every `std::string` implementation I am aware of uses small buffer optimization. Such implementations will never allocate when constructed with short strings (such as `"one"`).

3) The standard library runtime is allowed to call `operator new` during static initialization, for instance to setup `std::cout`. The allocations you see are most likely not related to the `string` constructor or (lack of) move.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments `one` and `two` are rvalue references to ***constant*** `std::string` objects. How can you move from a constant object?

Drop the `const` qualifier for the arguments. In most cases using the `const` qualifier doesn't make sense for rvalue references.

Or don't use *either* `const` nor rvalue references (and the compiler should create the correct code anyway).