# Can't understand the implementation of std::move

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Here is a possible implementation of `std::move()`. It's not fully conforming to the details of the standard, but it's very close:

```
template<class T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&
myMove( T&& Arg )
{   
    return ( ( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& )Arg );
}
```

I don't understand why it wouldn't work if we replace `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&` by the `T&&`, i.e.

```
template<class T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&
myMove( T&& Arg )
{   
    return ( (T&&) Arg );
}
```

Comment: `remove_reference<T>` of course is important if `T` already is a reference.

Comment: This is where `type_name` earns its keep: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/576911 :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is not really about the move, but the reference collapsing that happens with `T&&`.

The are nice write-ups about this [here](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html) and these Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3106110/3747990), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7518365/3747990).

I'll focus on the cast `(T&&)` and why that doesn't work.

Given the reference collapsing rules listed above;

- `T& &` becomes `T&`
- `T& &&` becomes `T&`
- `T&& &` becomes `T&`
- `T&& &&` becomes `T&&`

The problem arises when `T` is deduced to be an lvalue reference, then `T&&` becomes `T& &&` which collapses to `T&`, given the cast, you merely cast it back to an lvalue reference and you have not gained the rvalue reference that enables moving to happen.

The `std::remove_reference<T>::type` is there to remove all the references and the `&&` then adds back the rvalue ref and thus ensures the correct cast is made.

*The `typename` is there to disambiguate the member type over a member variable.*