# Why is std::move( arg ) altering arg argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Having code

```
string one = "one";
string two{ one };
string three{ move(one)};
cout << one  << endl;
```

this prints "". It is due to fact that moving constructor for string three is invoked and stole its argument value. However, how come variable one is modified?

When we pass `move(one)` rvalue is returned. And move constructor steals resource from THAT rvalue, the variable one is not passed as reference or pointer there. So how come behavior like this happen?

thanks for answers

Comment: `move(one)` gives you an rvalue *reference*.

Comment: *"the variable one is not passed as reference or pointer there. "* - Yes it is. `std::move()` does not create a temporary it performs a type cast. So THAT rvalue is `one` cast from lvalue to rvalue reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510182/how-does-stdmove-transfer-values-into-rvalues

Comment: How would the constructor know you keep around a reference to one? You explicitely specify with move(one) that you pass the ownership to the constructor, so the behaviour is legal

Comment: To be clear, `std::move(arg)` is just a cast. It's the constructor of `std::string` that alters the argument. This is precisely what `std::move` is for -- avoiding have to make a copy of the string's data.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that the string is empty. I would have thought the short string optimization would perhaps result in the characters being copied rather than a pointer being reassigned. Maybe there is some unnecessary housekeeping being done on the moved from string. Ok, I just checked; Seems like it does leave most of the short string in place on MSVC, it just places a null character in the first position.

Comment: What would be the reason to invent move semantics when it would create a copy like you think it should?

Comment: You should read that : [C++ Rvalue Reference explained](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html)

Answer (score 2):

#### `std::move()` does not actually alter its argument

... but it does let code *taking* its output "cannibalize" the argument. Thus your `three` string takes away `one`'s buffer, leaving it empty.

You can also read [this detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27026280/1593077) regarding `std::move()` here on the site (answering the question ["what is std::move() and when should it be used"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-is-stdmove-and-when-should-it-be-used)).

Answer (score 1):

In the title, you ask:

> Why is `std::move( arg )` altering `arg` argument?

`std::move(arg)` does not alter the contents of `arg`. It simply cast `arg` to an rvalue refence.

The call to the constructor of `std::string` with

```
string three{ move(one)};
```

alters the contents of `one` since it calls the "move" constructor.

That is the desired behavior. You are asking the compiler to "move" the data from `one` to `three`. The intention is to cannibalize the contents of `one` and to leave it in an *empty* state. Of course, the notion of *empty* is compiler specific.

You can read more about rvalue references, move constructors and move assignment operators at http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#rval.

Re:

> When we pass move(one) rvalue is returned.

That is not correct. `move(one)` returns an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 0):

> When we pass `move(one)` rvalue is returned. And move constructor steals resource from **THAT rvalue**, the variable one is not passed as reference or pointer there.

"THAT rvalue" is the `one` object. So `three` steals the data from `one`.

In this line:

```
string three{move(one)};
```

`three` receives an rvalue reference to `one`, so when it steals the data from that rvalue reference, it steals the data from `one`, since the rvalue reference **is** the `one` object.

Since `one` has a name and you can take its address, it is not an rvalue reference. Using `std::move()` you *cast* it to an rvalue reference, so that you can move from it. After you move from it, its state is *unspecified*. For an `std::string` this means that you can't know what it contains after moving from it. It could contain anything. It is still a valid `std::string` after the move, but its contents are unknown. In your particular compiler/library, it just so happens that the new state is an empty string.