# How does std::move invalidates the value of original variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics, stdmove

In the following examples from [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello";
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    // uses the push_back(const T&) overload, which means 
    // we'll incur the cost of copying str
    v.push_back(str);
    std::cout << "After copy, str is \"" << str << "\"\n";

    // uses the rvalue reference push_back(T&&) overload, 
    // which means no strings will be copied; instead, the
    // Contents of str will be moved into the vector.  This is
    // less expensive, but also means str might now be empty.
    v.push_back(std::move(str));
    std::cout << "After move, str is \"" << str << "\"\n";

    std::cout << "The contents of the vector are \"" << v[0]
              << "\", \"" << v[1] << "\"\n";
}
```

Using `std::move` may cause the original value be lost. To me, it looks like

```
v.push_back(std::move(str))
```

causes a new member `v[1]` being created. Then,

```
&v[1] = &str
```

But why should it damage the value in `str`? It does not make sense.

There are many complicated tutorials about `std::move` which are harder than my own question to understand.

Could any one please write

```
v.push_back(std::move(str))
```

in its equivalent using `c++03`?

I look for an explanation whose understanding is easy and do not contain prerequisites such as `x-value` , `static_cast`, `remove_reference`, etc, as they themselves require to understand `std::move` first. Please avoid this circular dependency.

Also these links do not answer my question: [7510182](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510182/how-does-stdmove-transfer-values-into-rvalues), [3413470](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-is-stdmove-and-when-should-it-be-used)

Because I am interested in knowing how `str` is harm and not what happens to `v[1]`.

Pseudo code is also welcome as far as it is as simple as `c++03`.

---

Update: To avoid complication, let's consider a simpler example of `int` as follows

```
int x = 10;
int y = std::move(x);
std::cout << x;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178313/discussion-on-question-by-ar2015-how-does-stdmove-invalidates-the-value-of-ori).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the implementation, the `std::move`  could be a simple swap of the internal memory addresses.

If you run the following code on http://cpp.sh/9f6ru

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string str1 = "test";
  std::string str2 = "test2";

  std::cout << "str1.data() before move: "<< static_cast<const void*>(str1.data()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "str2.data() before move: "<< static_cast<const void*>(str2.data()) << std::endl;

  str2 = std::move(str1);
  std::cout << "=================================" << std::endl;

  std::cout << "str1.data() after move: " << static_cast<const void*>(str1.data()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "str2.data() after move: " << static_cast<const void*>(str2.data()) << std::endl;
}
```

You will get the following output:

```
str1.data() before move: 0x363d0d8
str2.data() before move: 0x363d108
=================================
str1.data() after move: 0x363d108
str2.data() after move: 0x363d0d8
```

But the result may vary depending on the implementation of the compiler and the std library.

But the implementation details can be even more complex http://cpp.sh/6dx7j. If you look at your example, then you will see that creating a copy for a string does not necessarily require that new memory for its content is allocated. This is because nearly all operations on `std::string` are read only or require the allocation of memory. So the implementation can decide to do just shallow copies:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::string str = "Hello";
  std::vector<std::string> v;

  std::cout << "str.data() before move: "<< static_cast<const void*>(str.data()) << std::endl;

  v.push_back(str);
  std::cout << "============================" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "str.data()  after push_back: "<< static_cast<const void*>(str.data()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "v[0].data() after push_back: "<< static_cast<const void*>(v[0].data()) << std::endl;

  v.push_back(std::move(str));
  std::cout << "============================" << std::endl;

  std::cout << "str.data()  after move: "<< static_cast<const void*>(str.data()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "v[0].data() after move: "<< static_cast<const void*>(v[0].data()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "v[1].data() after move: "<< static_cast<const void*>(v[1].data()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "After move, str is \"" << str << "\"\n";


  str = std::move(v[1]);
  std::cout << "============================" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "str.data()  after move: "<< static_cast<const void*>(str.data()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "v[0].data() after move: "<< static_cast<const void*>(v[0].data()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "v[1].data() after move: "<< static_cast<const void*>(v[1].data()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "After move, str is \"" << str << "\"\n";
}
```

The output is

```
str.data() before move: 0x3ec3048
============================
str.data()  after push_back: 0x3ec3048
v[0].data() after push_back: 0x3ec3048
============================
str.data()  after move: 0x601df8
v[0].data() after move: 0x3ec3048
v[1].data() after move: 0x3ec3048
After move, str is ""
============================
str.data()  after move: 0x3ec3048
v[0].data() after move: 0x3ec3048
v[1].data() after move: 0x601df8
After move, str is "Hello"
```

And if you take a look at:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::string str = "Hello";
  std::vector<std::string> v;

  std::cout << "str.data() before move: "<< static_cast<const void*>(str.data()) << std::endl;

  v.push_back(str);
  std::cout << "============================" << std::endl;
  str[0] = 't';
  std::cout << "str.data()  after push_back: "<< static_cast<const void*>(str.data()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "v[0].data() after push_back: "<< static_cast<const void*>(v[0].data()) << std::endl;

}
```

Then you would assume that `str[0] = 't'`  would just replace the data in place. But this is not necessarily the case http://cpp.sh/47nsy.

```
str.data() before move: 0x40b8258
============================
str.data()  after push_back: 0x40b82a8
v[0].data() after push_back: 0x40b8258
```

And moving primitives like:

```
void test(int i) {
  int x=i;
  int y=std::move(x);
  std::cout<<x;
  std::cout<<y;
}
```

Would be mostly be optimized out completely by the compiler:

```
  mov ebx, edi
  mov edi, offset std::cout
  mov esi, ebx
  call std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
  mov edi, offset std::cout
  mov esi, ebx
  pop rbx
  jmp std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int) # TAILCALL
```

Both `std::cout`  used the same register, the `x` and `y` are completely optimized away.

Answer (score 6):

`std::move` is a simple cast-to-rvalue-reference. It doesn't actually *do* anything.

All the magic happens in functions *receiving* such an rvalue-reference, if they accept it as an rvalue-reference. They take it as **license to plunder** those objects ruthlessly, obviating the need to actually allocate resources and otherwise do the heavy work of making a copy. Swapping source and target to avoid even the need for cleanup is expected when assigning.

Thus, using move-semantics is generally more efficient (one can do less faster, trust me), and less likely to throw exceptions (resource-acquisition is prone to fail), for the cost of trashing the source.

And all of it is enabled by that small disguised cast known as `std::move`, which doesn't itself *do* anything.

Comment: Although they are at liberty to plunder ruthlessly, they must also leave the carcass in a valid but unspecified state.  That unspecified state is unspecified -- does not have to equate to an initialized state; but does need to be gracefully destructible.  Which, as an implementation detail, may just set a bool flag to say "I've been plundered!".