# Why does std::move copy contents for a rvalue or const lvalue function argument?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

If I use ***std::move*** on a stack object in the current scope, the contents are moved to destination leaving the source empty.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string str("stackoverflow");

    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(std::move(str));
    std::cout << "vec[0]: " << vec[0] << std::endl;

    std::cout << "str: " << str << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
vec[0]: stackoverflow
str:
```

If I use the ***std::move*** for a rvalue or const lvalue function arguments, the contents are copied.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

void process_copy(std::vector<int> const & vec_)
{
    std::vector<int> vec(vec_);
    vec.push_back(22);
    std::cout << "In process_copy (const &): " << std::endl;
    for(int & i : vec)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void process_copy(std::vector<int> && vec_)
{
    std::vector<int> vec(vec_);
    vec.push_back(99);
    std::cout << "In process_copy (&&): " << std::endl;
    for(int & i : vec)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    process_copy(std::move(v));

    std::cout << "In main: " << std::endl;
    for(int & i : v)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size: " << v.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
In process_copy (&&): 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 99 
In main: 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
size: 10
```

Why is the behavior of std::move different?

Comment: Remember that `std::move` doesn't actually move anything. It is just a *cast* to rvalue reference. Whether that rvalue reference is subsequently moved or copied depends on context and whether or not the object implements move operations and whether or not the source object is `const`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510182/how-does-stdmove-transfer-values-into-rvalues

Comment: In the first example, the one `actually moving the ownership of the data` is the move constructor of the std::string.
In the second example, you're just sending an rvalue ref. You can manually take the ownership of the passed std::vector here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vector is actually copied, not moved. The reason for this is, although declared as an rvalue reference, `vec_` denotes an **lvalue** expression inside the function body. Thus the copy constructor of `std::vector` is invoked, and not the move constructor. The reason for this is, that `vec_` is now a named value, and rvalues cannot have names, so it collapses to an lvalue. The following code will fail to compile because of this reason:

```
void foo(int&& i)
{
    int&& x = i;
}
```

In order to fix this issue, you have to make `vec_` *nameless* again, by calling `std::move(vec_)`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `std::move` if the value is bound to a variable even it is declared as rvalue revefernce (`&&`). i.e. it should be:

```
void process_copy(std::vector<int> && vec_)
{
    std::vector<int> vec(std::move(vec_));
    ...
}
```

Comment: To add to this, one should note that the one actually transferring the ownership of the data is the move constructor.

Comment: Is it not std::forward which should be used to give a better readability in that case?

Comment: @Klaus `vec_` is not a forwarding reference so I'd say `move` is better suited.

Comment: @Klaus It is true that std::forward will work as well but we should understand the purpose of std::forward i.e. "perfect-forwarding". Here vec_ is an rvalue ref, so it's better to just straightaway use std::move, which is meant for this.

Comment: @theWiseBro: OK, got it! Thanks!