# Why is static_cast<Object&&> necessary in this function?

Tags: c++, types, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, stdmove

Trying to understand `std::move`, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7518365) to another question.

Say I have this function

```
Object&& move(Object&& arg)
{
    return static_cast<Object&&>(arg);
}
```

What I think I understand:

- `arg` is an lvalue (***value category***).
- `arg` is of ***type*** "rvalue ref to Object".
- `static_cast` converts ***types***.
- `arg` and the return type both being of ***type*** "rvalue ref to Object", the `static_cast` is unnecessary.

However, the linked answer says:

> Now, you might wonder: do we even need the cast? The answer is: yes, we do. The reason is simple; named rvalue reference is treated as lvalue (and implicit conversion from lvalue to rvalue reference is forbidden by standard).

I still don't understand why the static_cast is necessary given what I said above.

Comment: because arg has a name and *named rvalue reference is treated as lvalue*. So it's not an "rvalue ref to object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the static_cast is unnecessary.

It may seem so, but it is necessary. You can find out easily by attempting to write such function without the cast, as the compiler should tell you that the program is ill-formed. The function (template) returns an rvalue reference. That rvalue reference cannot be bound to an lvalue. The id-expression `arg` is an lvalue (as you stated) and hence the returned rvalue reference cannot be bound to it.

It might be easier to understand outside of return value context. The rules are same here:

```
T obj;
T&& rref0 = obj;                     // lvalue; not OK
T&& rref1 = static_cast<T&&>(obj);   // xvalue; OK
T&& rref2 = rref1;                   // lvalue; not OK
T&& rref3 = static_cast<T&&>(rref1); // xvalue; OK
```

Comment: Ok, so I don't understand what `static_cast` is doing. I thought `static_cast` was only converting types. `rref1` already being of ***type*** T&&, the static_cast still seems unecessary on the last line. So what is `static_cast` doing that I am missing?

Comment: @Gradient Simply, the value category of a static cast expression of rvalue reference type is xvalue. That's all that it's doing.

Comment: I see. Thank you! And this is also explained in point 2) of this page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast.

Comment: @Gradient you actually also have a fundamental misunderstanding that `arg` of `std::move` is an lvalue. it isn't. That's where logic begins to break up.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following mental model for it (let's use `int` instead of `Object`).

Objects which have a name are "sitting on the ground". They are lvalues; you cannot convert them to rvalue references.

```
int do_stuff(int x, int&& y) {...} // both x and y have a name
```

When you do calculations, you pick objects from the ground, do your stuff in mid-air and put the result back.

```
x + y; // it's in mid-air
do_stuff(4, 5); // return value is in mid-air
```

These temporary results can be converted to rvalue references. But as soon as you "put them onto the ground", they behave as lvalues.

```
int&& z = x + y; // on the ground
int&& z = do_stuff(6, 7); // on the ground
```

I am sure it only helps in simple situations, but at least it gives some real-world analogy to how C++ works.

Answer (score 0):

Your first bullet is incorrect fundamentally, `arg` is not a lvalue, neither it is an rvalue. Neither it's a rvalue or lvalue reference, because `std::move` is a template. In template context a function argument of type `T&&` is a *forwarding reference*, if `T` is a template-parameter. Forwarding reference becomes of type which appropriate, depending on what is T.

> (and implicit conversion from lvalue to rvalue reference is forbidden by standard).

A cast is required literally because of that. Following code is incorrect, because you can't call `foo(v)`, as `v` is a named object and it can be an lvalue:

```
void foo(int && a) { a = 5; }

int main()
{
    int v;
    foo(v);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

But if `foo()` is a template, it may become a function with `int&`, `const int&` and `int&&` arguments.

```
template<class T>
void foo(T && a) { a = 5; }
```

You would be able to call `foo(v+5)`, where argument is a temporary, which can be bound to rvalue reference. `foo` will change the temporary object which stops to exist after function call. That's the exact action which move constructors usually have to do - to modify  temporary object before its destructor is called.

*NB: An rvalue argument would cease to exist earlier , either after its use or at end of function call.*

Forwarding references are a special kind of reference syntax designed to preserve the value category of a function argument. I.e. non-template function

```
Object&& move(Object&& arg)
```

is not equal to `std::move` for `Object`, which declared something like  (c++11):

```
template<class T>
std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move( T&& t );
```

In non-template function `arg` is an lvalue, in template it have same value category as expression used to initialize it. In template `std::remove_reference<T>::type` refers to T, so `std::remove_reference<T>::type&&` is a true rvalue reference to T - a way around `T&&` alternative meaning.

By analogy to function call above, if implicit conversion was possible, then it would be possible to call move constructor where copy constructor is appropriate but missing, i.e. by mistake. `return static_cast<Object&&>(arg);` results in initialization involving call to `Object::Object(Object&&)` by definition of `return`, `return arg` would call `Object::Object(const Object&)`.

Template `std::move` is type-correct "wrapper" around the `static_cast` to facilitate "implicit" cast, to simplify code by removing repeated `static_cast` with explicit type from code.

Comment: My first bullet specified that I was talking about the ***value category*** of `arg`, not its ***type***. See my first 2 bullets (`arg` is an lvalue (***value category***) of ***type*** "rvalue ref to Object". Also `Object` in my question was not meant to be a template, to keep things simple. I believe you are talking about the type in this answer and it does not contradict `arg` having lvalue ***value category***, right?

Comment: @Gradient Expression, consisting of rvalue reference is an lvalue, that's true. But in template `arg` ismay or may not be rvalue reference after substitution. `T&& arg` does not have type of rvalue reference, if `T` is not rvalue reference. Value category in this case is determined **after substitution**, and if code following it isn't not legal in result, that's compilation error. Your non-template function `move` as you declared is useless and isn't equivalent of `std::move`, because it would require a `static_cast` to pass an argument to it in cases when `std::move` is legal.

Comment: I think the value category of the expression `arg` is ***always*** an lvalue. [On the Value categories page of cppreference (1st bullet for lvalues)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), it is said that the name of a variable is an lvalue and this is not dependent on its type.