# How to implement move functionality without any reference to std::move or std::swap?

Tags: c++, std, move

How to implement move functionality without any reference to `std::move` or `std::swap`?

What is a standard function prototype acceptable by STL, and how to use it?

Please, give an example. I tried to search StackOverflow.

I want to implement this for a class in a project which does not have any reference to STL (and it must not!). But, in a test project, I use STL. Anything in StackOverflow references the `std::move` or `std::swap` functions. I have to avoid them to satisfy both goals.

Comment: `std::move` is just casting of type. Check documentation it provides possible implementation.

Comment: You don't need the STL to implement move semantics. For example if your class contains a heap allocated pointer, then just assign the pointer to the target object, and set the pointer to null in the source object. It's as simple as that.

Comment: The prototypes required to implement move semantics are not determined by the STL but by the C++ language. For a move constructor the signature is `X::X(X&&)` and for the move assignment it is `X& X::operator=(X&&)`.

Comment: *a project which does not have any reference to stl* - This is like working on a keyboard with some keys not allowed to be pressed.

Comment: You can implement your own version of `std::move` and `std::swap`, it doesn't require any compiler support. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510182/how-does-stdmove-convert-expressions-to-rvalues for how to implement `std::move`, with which it is pretty easy to implement a `std::swap` analogue.

Comment: You don't implement move functionality but you use it. It is part of C++ and like pointers and references there are `rvalue references` denoted by &&.  All std::move does is make an rvalue reference for you so you can call the correct overloads. Maybe reading this https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/rvalue-references/ will help you a bit

Comment: Side note: I don't think the STL ever supported move semantics, but I can't say for sure since I haven't used the STL since around 2003. Someone may have updated it for C++11.

Comment: @user4581301 There are a lot of forks of STL, and Microsoft's standard library implementation which contains code derived from the STL also still calls its implementation "STL". So depending on the definition of "STL" you could argue that at least one fork of it does support move semantics.

Comment: *"I tried to search StackOverflow."* -- What did you search for? I did the simplest search I could think of for your topic, `[c++] move`, and [the second hit's top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981) shows a move constructor that uses neither `std::move` nor `std::swap`. While the assignment operator in that answer does use `std::swap`, you could easily replace that with a member `swap` function (which in some cases is what `std::swap` would end up calling anyway).

Answer (score 0):

`std::move()` is done by casting to a `T&&`. You can cast by hand, or create your own move function:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T&& move(T& t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

Comment: A complete implementation of move is a bit more complex. Current, this solution fails if the argument is already an rvalue expression (https://godbolt.org/z/nxf8oK1rd). Your solution is missing a [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) (but that can also be implemented without compiler support in just a few lines). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7518365/7359094).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  Read the code above again.  The function takes in a reference to T for a reason.  Type T is cannot be a reference by design.  The parameter `t` must be an lvalue for `move()` to work, so the parameter to `std::move()` is always an lvalue reference.  This implementation is complete.

Comment: `The parameter t must be an lvalue for move() to work` Ah, not it doesn't: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a89429c651c4a13b

Comment: @NathanOliver.  My bad, you're right.  In any case implementation above works the same as std::move, except for the one case when std::move is not used.  https://godbolt.org/z/5Ez6aWqcz

Comment: It does not seem working.

Comment: @IgorPolkovnikov  That is kind of vague.  **What** is not working?  You can post example on godbolt and paste link in comment.

Answer (score -6):

Is this sufficient? Should another funciton be implemented?

```
MyClass(MyClass&& o)
{
    memcpy(this, &o, sizeof(MyClass));    
};
```

Thank you, john!
Amending with:

```
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass && o) noexcept
{
    memcpy(this, &o, sizeof(MyClass));
    return *this;
}
```

Is it good enough?

Comment: What's wrong with `MyClass(MyClass&& o) = default`?

Comment: Better stick an `static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<MyClass>);` in those functions to avoid being surprised.

Comment: It is unusual for the move assignment operator to take its argument as `const`. It is a clear sign that the operator doesn't actually move, and any provided copy assignment operator should be used instead or that the move assignment operator should be a copy assignment operator instead.

Comment: Again, STL MUST NOT BE USED! It is the requirement. Remove -1 !
Copy assignment  IS NOT A MOVE !!!

Comment: `memcpy` is part of the standard library so you are already contradicting yourself.  A move operation steals the guts from the moved from object.  `memcpy` does no such thing, it makes a copy, so you are not moving.

Comment: Dear Nathan, memcpy is not a part of the C++ standard library called STL.  It is a part of C-runtime library. memcpy is far from what is expected from a copy assignment. Copy assignment must recreate the full deep structure of the object copied while memcpy only copies the top level leaving everthing else intact, without any additional  heap memory allocation.

Comment: Why do you think [std::memcpy()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) has been placed into `namespace std`?

Comment: @IgorPolkovnikov: Many people, including OP, mistakenly say STL or "Standard Template Library" when they mean "C++ Standard Library".  The actual STL never had any `std::`anything, let alone `std::move` or `std::swap`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This will cause undefined behavior not only if the class isn't trivially copyable, but also if `*this` is a potentially-overlapping subobject, e.g. if the class is used as a base for another class. OP: Using `memcpy` like this in C++ is really dangerous if you do not have a very good understanding of its restrictions in the language. You generally don't need it. And also, your implementation has nothing to do with move semantics at all. If you just want to copy the class contents, then there is no point in move semantics or having the move operations defined.

Comment: Well, give me the correct implementation ( working one with an example). Not using any std:: , please.That is what I am asking.. (by the way, coping of an object is not the same as moving..). Rememeber, during move, no any constructor, nor any operator= which actually copies the object should be called.

Comment: "_Rememeber, during move, no any constructor, nor any operator= which actually copies the object should be called._": No, that's not the difference between move and copy. I think you are mistaken how move semantics work. The correct implementation is, assuming you correctly follow the rule-of-0/3/5 everywhere, to simply not declare any copy or move constructor/assignment at all, i.e. to follow the rule-of-0 when possible. If not possible, then your class ought to be directly managing a resource and the move constructor should move that resource from the source object (e.g. a file handle).

Comment: How exactly moving vs copying for that resource needs to work depends on what exactly the resource is. There can't possibly be a generic answer to the question. An in any case, none of that depends on `std::move`.

Comment: I do not need a generic answer nor any move semantics. All I need is enabling a class (without any help from std::, that is the requirement) to "move freely" within an stl collection classes when they are resizing without any calls to class or any of its members to any constructor or destructor. Anything which is not stored in, say, a vector buffer, and under any algorithm on it, has to stay intact.